# How to find that all input text boxes are empty in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table with data like

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In JQuery

```js
$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("keyup", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function() {
   if(all the textboxes are empty)
    // do something
});
```

I am trying to find out how will I check that all text boxes in the table are empty.

Note that text boxes with "hide" class are hidden and are used for other purpose.

Please help!!!

Comment: IDs cannot be identical.

Comment: Do you want  to find empty input's with class ```hide``` as well? Also ID's cannot be identical.

Comment: You will have to fetch all input. Once you have them, loop over and filter out any and every input that does not satisfy your need.

Comment: @A.Wolff Though an opinionated comment, but instead of giving code, we could explain how to do it and OP can try to figure the code part. If he/she fails then we can give proper code example with explanation. But just my POV

Comment: No I don't to do anything with hide classed textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this
***This code will work only for second input.***

```
$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("keyup", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function() {
        var oneEmpty = false;
        $("#library_info_tbl tbody tr td input:nth-child(2)").filter(function () {
              return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
        });
        if(oneEmpty)
        // do something
 });
```

***This code will work only for all input.***

```
$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("keyup", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function() {

        if($("#library_info_tbl tbody input:empty").length == $("#library_info_tbl tbody input").length)
        {
        // do something
        }
 });

// Instead of $("#library_info_tbl tbody input:empty") you can also use $("input.hide:empty")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var allempty = true;
$('.hide').each(function(){
       if($(this).val()!=''){
          allempty = false;
       }else{
          allempty = true;
       }
    });

if(allempty) {
   //this is empty
}
```

Comment: it will work for all "hide" class, if you want it works only for textbox, just add another class in the textbox, and replace $('.hide') with $('.otherclass')

Answer (score 1):

you can use `input[type=text]` as selector :

For i.e. :

```
var emptyValues = 0;
$('table input[type=text]').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() != ''){
      console.log($(this).val());
      emptyValues = 1;
   }
});
if(emptyValues == 0){
   //enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the id of your table is `tableId`, you could try:

```
if($("table#tableId input[class!='hide'][value='']").length == $("table#tableId input[class!='hide']").length) {
// do something
}
```

or simply:

```
if($("table input[class!='hide'][value='']").length == $("table input[class!='hide']").length) {
// do something
}
```

Comment: Will it work also for `                    ` Blank space ?

Comment: No, because `' '`  does not mean empty, right? I don't think you can use a selector combined with trim. You should have another approach if you need to check blank spaces also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by for loop iteration and check each value

```js
function checkEmpty(){
  var elems = $("table input[type=text]");
  var isEmpty = false;
  for(let i=0 ; i < elems.length;i++){
    if($(elems[i]).val().trim() != ''){
      isEmpty = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  $("#isempty").html(isEmpty?'All Not Empty':'All Empty');
  //return isEmpty;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb0" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode0" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>781</td>
    <td><input id="barcodedb1" class="hide" type="text" /><input id="barcode1" class="hide" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input onclick="checkEmpty()" type="button" value="check empty"/>
<div id="isempty"></div>
```

*Care about duplicate id's*